# Passing many variables as one variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, arguments

I have a list of variables that I want to send to my function. (so the function works based on the values on those variables).

One way is to pass each variable separately in the function like this:

```
def my_function(var1, var2, var3, var4, ..., varn):
   output = var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + .... + varn
```

However, I wonder if I can write such a thing:

```
def my_function(parameters):
    output = parameters.var1 + parameters.var2 + ... + parameters.varn
```

That is, somehow is there any way to wrap all variables in one variable, and then call them like this?

I know the above python codes are not correct, I just want to express my question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: pass those variable in a list and then do summation ?

Comment: Maybe you may use **kwargs? https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of *variables*. You don't pass variables, you pass *objects*. Put your objects into another object, like a list, or a dict, or as members of an instance of a user-defined class

Comment: Alternatively, use some sort of variadic argument, which will basically put your arguments into a data structure for you, a tuple or a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options. You have to determine which way fits your case.

**Option 1. Getting multiple arguments by a single asterisk**

```
def my_function(*args):
    output = sum(args)

    # SAME WITH
    # output = args[0] + args[1] + ... + args[n]
    #
    # PASSING ARGUMENTS EXAMPLE
    # my_function(10, 20, 10, 50)
```

**Option 2. Getting keyword arguments by double asterisk**

```
def my_function(**kwargs):
    output = sum(kwargs.values())
    
    # SAME WITH
    # output = kwargs["var0"] + kwargs["var1"] + ... + kwargs["varn"]
    #
    # PASSING ARGUMENTS EXAMPLE
    # my_function(var0=10, var1=20, var2=15)
```

**Option 3. Getting an argument as a list**

```
def my_function(list_arg):
    output = sum(list_arg)

    # SAME WITH
    # output = list_arg[0] + list_arg[1] + ... + list_arg[n]
    #
    # PASSING ARGUMENTS EXAMPLE
    # my_function([1, 10, 3, -10])
```

**Option 4. Getting an argument as a dictionary**

```
def my_function(dict_arg):
    output = sum(dict_arg.values())

    # SAME WITH
    # output = kwargs["var0"] + kwargs["var1"] + ... + kwargs["varn"]
    #
    # PASSING ARGUMENTS EXAMPLE
    # my_function({"var0":5, "var1":10, "var2":3})
```